# SQL Server : remove substring results from result set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[Please help with the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBKAX.jpg)

Please help with the T-SQL query

Let's assume the table has the data like below

```
| ID  | Name | FullName |
|  1  | a    | a        |
|  2  | b    | ab       |
|  3  | c    | abc      |
|  4  | d    | ad       |
|  5  | e    | ade      |
|  6  | i    | i        |
|  7  | g    | ig       |
```

I want to get the result set as below

```
| ID | Name | FullName |
| 3  | c    | abc      | 
| 5  | e    | ade      |
| 7  | g    | ig       |
```

Comment: why the question was downgraded? is the problem not clear?

Comment: Please show your existing query and detail how you want the result set to be filtered. Also, I recommend you review the [help center article on asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Following that guideline will greatly improve your changes of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: exclude those rows based on the column "FullName" if the value is a substring in another row's value

Comment: please elaborate on the logic of you query. this is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

To check for a substring you can use the builtin [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. The subquery looks for any rows that have a substring match to any other row. Those ids are then filtered from the final result set.

```
create table #example (
    Id int, [Name] varchar(255), [FullName] varchar(255)
);
go

insert into #example (Id, Name, FullName)
values
(1, 'a', 'a'),
(2, 'b', 'ab'),
(3, 'c', 'abc'),
(4, 'd', 'ad'),
(5, 'e', 'ade'),
(6, 'i', 'i'),
(7, 'g', 'ig');
go



select *
from #example as a where a.Id not in (
    select distinct
        a.Id
    from
        #example as a
        inner join #example as b
        on a.Id <> b.Id -- don't check against yourself
        and charindex(a.FullName, b.FullName, 0) > 0 -- if charindex > 0 then there is a substring match
)
```